Steady-state wave equation
I know that for the heat equation $u_t=\nabla^2u$, the steady-state condition $u_t=0$ suggests we need to solve $\nabla^2u=0$ (i.e. Laplace's equation), which yields the equilibrium temperature distribution after a considerable amount of time.
However, for the wave equation, say $u_{tt}=\nabla^2u$, if we consider when $u_{tt}$ is identically zero, what can we say about wave propagations here?
The only thing I found online about steady-state waves seem to mention something about elastic waves?

When $u_{tt}$ is identically zero we have a static situation. A static electric and/or magnetic field for example. Or a body under static stress. There are no waves.
Edit: Besides static situations, it is also possible linearly increasing or decreasing of a function. A good example is a rod subject to a tensile test, if the load is being increased linearly with the time.

Wait that's not quite true, though—we could have a solution on a finite domain that's a harmonic function, so $\nabla^2 f = 0$, but it has a constant time derivative $\dot{f} = \alpha$.  This is not a static solution. (edited)

You are right. A temporarily linearly increasing electric field for example. But anyway, there are no waves in this case.
